# Make Lazy initialization objects as null, while object is with hibernate proxy in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For example I have three classes as follows

```
User{
   Integer id;
   ...
}

Book{
  Integer id;
  ....

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.lazy)
  User insertedBy;
}

Author{
   Integer id;
   List<Book> books;
}
```

Now I need to show the ***author list*** with their written ***books*** in same page
so I fetch authors with **findAll()** method using **jpa** repository. here I don't need the inserted by 
column of books so I mad them with *lazy load*.

When I tried to converts these author lists into json object with Gson. 
it gives lazy load exception in User class (Hibernate proxy... no session found.....)

I have followed many of the ways given in this network like **TypeAdapters**.
nothing helps me.
I just wanted to make **insertedBy** column of **Books** as **null** in lazy load.

for now I am using **Dto** classes to avoid insertedBy / make insertedBy as null.

Is there any other simple way without converting it into Dto.

I faced this issue many times. all those time I was end up with converting into Dto.

If anyone knows the answer please help me solve.

Comment: Does your `User` class have a `List<Book>` field, which is properly mapped with Hibernate?

Comment: When you convert an object to JSON, getters of all the fields will be called. When the getter of `insertedBy` will be called (when hibernate session is closed) it will throw **lazy load exception**. If you want to ignore this field to be converted to JSON you simply have to annotate this field with `@JsonIgnore` and now it will not be converted to JSON.

Comment: DTOs are the way to go in this case. It's usually a bad idea to expose your domain  model to you frontend/API/Integration layer. Having a DTO makes that distinction clear and allows both to evolve independently.

Comment: Mushif Ali Nawaz, In book listing page I need to show the insertedBy column. if I make that field as jsonIgnore their I may not able to use that column

Comment: Augusto, that's what I follow right now, if I have plenty of scenarios like this, then the converting codes has to be written for each module. If I go with class converting machanism like Dozer mapper, those functionality takes huge time to convert list of records. which makes application slower

Comment: @Sam here you have two different scenarios. In one case you want to show the field and in the second case, you don't want to show the field. This will not be possible when using Domain classes (because either you can mark it `@JsonIgnore` or you don't mark it). You can't achieve both scenarios. Probably you should be using `DTO` here. And then decide which fields you want to expose for that particular request.

Comment: If you use the `MapStruct` or `JMapper` tools, [performance will not be a problem](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"lazy-load" in Hibernate means children does not actually get loaded when loading the parent, typically when you try to access a child during iteration it gets loaded. In your case you receive this lazy load exception because by the time when gson try to access the child to map it to a JSON object the session has closed already.

May be you can ask GSON to ignore that field while mapping to JSON by using ExclusionStrategy class provided by Gson.

Comment: [Guide how to use it](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-exclude-or-ignore-fields/)